Why does a ReplaySubject emit its values in wrong order?
I have a RxJS ReplaySubject and for some reason, it is emitting its values in an unexpected order.
Let's say the values are simple numbers and the numbers 1-3 were already emitted before the code subscribes to the subject. After the subscription, the values 4 and 5 are emitted as well. So I would expect the values to be emitted in sequential order:
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5

but the values are actually emitted like this:
1 - 4 - 5 - 2 - 3

Can anyone explain how this can happen?

After some investigation, I found out that the problem is that the values 4 and 5 are emitted synchronously within the subscription to the ReplaySubject.
It seems that values that are emitted within a subscription to a ReplaySubject are emitted "immediately" so before the remaining values from the ReplaySubject's buffer are emitted.
Here is a code example which demonstrates the problem:


const myReplaySubj = new rxjs.ReplaySubject();

myReplaySubj.next( 1 );
myReplaySubj.next( 2 );
myReplaySubj.next( 3 );

let didEmitNewValues = false;

myReplaySubj.subscribe( ( val ) => {
  console.log( val );
  if( !didEmitNewValues ) { // Avoid infinite recursion
    didEmitNewValues = true;
    myReplaySubj.next( 4 );
    myReplaySubj.next( 5 );
  }
} );
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>



So the solution is to not call next() synchronously within the subscription.
For example, emitting the new values asynchronously solves it:


const myReplaySubj = new rxjs.ReplaySubject();

myReplaySubj.next( 1 );
myReplaySubj.next( 2 );
myReplaySubj.next( 3 );

let didEmitNewValues = false;

myReplaySubj.subscribe( ( val ) => {
  console.log( val );
  if( !didEmitNewValues ) { // Avoid infinite recursion
    didEmitNewValues = true;
    setTimeout( () => {
      myReplaySubj.next( 4 );
      myReplaySubj.next( 5 );
    }, 0 );
  }
} );
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>




One very important hint from me: you should never next values inside a subscription. You can use combination operators and others to achieve the same. This is not how RxJS is intended and causes unexpected side-effects.
